# VBA Macro crashing when starting up on different worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

Currently in Excel I have a workbook that has 3 worksheets on it.

Initially the workbook was provided by another company with written code for the macro. I began to optimize the code and the workbook a bit but unfortunately when I save the on worksheet2-3 and exit. Start up the workbook and open up where I left off, the macro "ends or debugs" and basically bugs out where as if I save and exit out on worksheet1 then start up, no issues.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Would help if you included your code.

Comment: Suggest you post the relevant portion of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have inherited a pretty frail VBA macro there.

Hard to tell exactly what the issue is without the actual code, but look for a handler method called `Workbook_Open` in `ThisWorkbook`, and expect to see code (or code that calls code) that assumes the active sheet is "Sheet1" at startup.

This could possibly work around the issue (without really solving the problem though):

```
Sub Workbook_Open()
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate

    'rest of the code
    '...

End Sub
```